# Search for Matrix Block by Date in plugin

Tags: plugin-development, matrix, datetime

I am trying to search for specific matrix blocks by date like so:

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::MatrixBlock);

$criteria->ownerId = $entry->id;

$criteria->type = 'myMatrixBlockType';

$criteria->myMatrixBlockDateField = "2016-06-01 04:00:00";

$criteria->limit = 10;

$blocks = $criteria->find();
```

It seems that no matter what format the date is, all blocks from the matrix field in the entry are returned. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `fieldId` param to make Craft join the content table.

```
$criteria->fieldId = $matrixFieldId;
```